# How to generate random numbers without making new Random objects?

Tags: c#, random

I'm using this as part of a game, but it's not really a game development question, so I'm putting it on this more general Stack Exchange.

The goal is to generate "random" outputs for a fixed integer input, but (and this is the clincher) to generate the *same* random output every time the *same* random input is put in.

The idea here is that the function will generate the world the same way every time, so we don't need to store anything; the function itself is the storage.  Unfortunately access speed is a little slow, because the only way I can find to generate random numbers is to create a new Random() object with a seed based on the input, which is surprisingly slow.

Is there a better way?  I'm not worried about crypto-safe generation; in fact I'm just going to pick a random seed in advance and expose it quite publicly.

The current code looks like this:

```
private const int seed;

public MapCell GetMapCell(int x, int y)
{
    Random ran = new Random(seed + (x ^ y));
    return new MapCell(ran.NextInt(0, 4));
}
```

Where the `MapCell` is one of four types (in fact it's more complicated than this, but not a whole lot).  The point is that this could be called for any parameters, at any time, in no particular order, but it needs to return the same answer every time, if x and y are the same every time.  That's why I can't fix a certain Random object and use it repeatedly.

I also don't want to store anything, because I want to keep the RAM usage quite low, but allow the player to wander freely to the edges of `Int.MaxValue`

Comment: "which is surprisingly slow" How slow? IMO this is only possible way, unless you want to save the whole world.

Comment: Also, how do you want to handle changes in generation algorithm itself?

Comment: Just generating a lot of objects that way (say, when you're scrolling quite quickly around the map) seems to cause trouble.  I'm not sure what you mean by changes in generation algorithm.  I think what's to be done is to find a numerical "random number generator" (repeatable, deterministic, mathematical process) which turns two numbers into an apparently unrelated third number and runs quickly.

Comment: Are you sure the bottlenect is random number generator? Random in C# is repeatable, deterministic and mathematical process. It is also quite fast. I would first try to optimize the generation algorithm first.

Comment: It's apparent that my question was unclear, so I've added a code sample.

Comment: I feel like you're not understanding how Random works.  It's intended to give you a *sequence* of random numbers.  You don't need to create a bunch of different Random instances.  You just need one with a given seed, which will return you the same sequence of random numbers every time.  Random is not like the RND() back in BASIC days that would give you *one* random number.  Your application only needs *one* instance of the Random class from which to generate *all* of its random numbers.

Comment: @KYralessa: I do understand how the Random class works.  Unfortunately I want to use it for something other than its intended purpose, and it's not the right tool.  That's why I went on StackExchange- looking for a better tool.

Comment: I have a feeling what you're looking for is some sort of noisy function, where the seed is the 'setup', and x and y are the inputs.

Comment: OK, I see what you're talking about.  But my next question is: What's so bad about just creating that many `Random` instances?  It's not as though you have to *keep* them.  They'll get garbage-collected when they need to be.  You say this is too slow...but just how slow is it?  How slow will it be in game time, when the user is wandering the map?  Perhaps you'll only need to generate one small region at a time.

Comment: How many cells do you need to generate? 100? 100 million? If the number is lowish, I find it hard to believe that the performance is even measurable. Are you doing this repeatedly in a tight rendering loop or something? Are you sure its the Random() call, and not creating the MapCell object that is slow?

Comment: @X-Zero yes that's precisely it.

Comment: To Kyralessa & GrandmasterB: It's quite possible I have the wrong culprit for the framerate issues

Comment: Given up trying to fix my answer and deleted it. One thing is still not clear: is it intended that [4, 3] should generate the same number as [3, 4], or is that a bug that needs fixing?

Comment: It is not intended, and this is not a good bit of code for that and many other reasons.

Comment: Do you know anything about x and y?  Are they likely to be less than 65000?  Are they likely to be the same? Are they ever negative? And so on.

Comment: @Eric this post is several years old, and the code is long gone. However, the code needed to work for any two integers (including large and/or negative numbers). The variables could absolutely be equal and that is an annoying case for the above.

Comment: @RichardRast: I didn't think to check the date! :-) Not sure why it showed up in the active queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sign is on a good track, but his algorithm is wrong. It is not much random. It is actually pretty hard to create random like this. I was playing around with this and everything I tried created obvious patterns when printed in 2D. In the end I manged to create an algorithm that doesn't create any eye-visible patterns. I looked for inspiration in existing random algorithms.

```
public static uint bitRotate(uint x)
{
    const int bits = 16;
    return (x << bits) | (x >> (32 - bits));
}

public static uint getXYNoise(int x, int y)
{
    UInt32 num = seed;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        num = num * 541 + (uint)x;
        num = bitRotate(num);
        num = num * 809 + (uint)y;
        num = bitRotate(num);
        num = num * 673 + (uint)i;
        num = bitRotate(num);
    }
    return num % 4;
}
```

When this algorithm is used to render a 4-shades of gray image, it creates this:
[image: random noise]

For comparison, the Random algorithm creates this pattern:[image]

And Sign's algorithm too has patterns: [image]

Answer (score 3):

In The Art of Computer programming, volume 2 there is a section dedicated to random numbers.  You might be able to find what you are looking for in there.

---

Project Euler uses the following psuedo random number generator in a few of its problems (252 and 375 are the ones I spotted first):

```
  S(0)   = 290797 
  S(n+1) = (S(n))^2 mod 50515093
```

Obviously, this doesn't give you a walk up to maxint, but it gives an approach to your own that only requires you save the last result.  If you are working with longs instead of ints, it would let work (for what its worth, 2^32-5 = 0xFFFFFFFB = 4,294,967,291 is the largest 32 bit prime).

---

In the talk [rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) the presenter goes over a number of different options for doing random numbers.  While that talks of C++, it does give information that can be used to find a the right method in other languages.

In particular, for well known uniform random number distributions the thing you want to find is `mt19937` which stands for the [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) with very particular parameters - its based on 2<sup>19937</sup> - 1. (~11m into the talk).

The key with the Mersenne twister is that it is very high quality pseudo-random numbers.  If you poke around a bit, you can find implementations of it in [a number of languages](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html).  The [original C source](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/mt19937-64.c)

Specfically, for C# you can use [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [StaticRandom](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/staticrandom.html) to get random numbers in a thread safe way - no instantiation of new objects needed ([code](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/)).  A modification of the code should allow you to pass in a seed.

Comment: +1 for what looks like Blum Blum Shub up top from TAOCP and the Mersenne Twister reference for more accurate stuff. I just implemented Blum Blum Shub in JS for this exact sort of scenario where I needed reproducible pseudo-randomness and it works pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just combine the two numbers and hash them? something like

```
private const int seed;

public MapCell GetMapCell(int x, int y)
{
    int combined = seed + (x ^ y);
    return new MapCell(combined.GetHashCode() %5);
}
```

You want to simply map each X,Y coordinate to a MapCell.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the GetHashCode() function that might work really well.  Looking at it now.

Comment: One would assume that the simplest implementation of a hashcode on an integer object would be to return the integer itself?  I'm not sure how 'noisy' this would be (the distribution), but I think this is the direction the OP is looking.

Comment: Turns out that is the hashcode (or something quite a bit like it).  Not very noisy, but this is spiritually the right approach.

Comment: It is as noisy as you want.  His example just relies on C#'s int hash code, which isn't very randomized (its built for speed).  There are very simple hash algorithms based on integers which will provide the noise you are looking for.  The only reason to use Random() is because it will generate more statistically random behavior over long periods.  From your question, the quality of the randomness is not a high priority, so a hash is an easy solution.

Answer (score -1):

As commented by Kyralessa, the Random class should be created and the sequence requested from the one instance. This saves the time of creating a new class instance.

```
//fixed seed of 123
private Random ran = new Random(123);
public MapCell GetMapCell(int x, int y)
{
    //x and y should not be zero
    int r = ran.Next(0,x*y*4)%4;
    return new MapCell(r);
}
```

Comment: This is a very old question to be answering, but no, this won't work; the _most_ important requirement is to be deterministic. If I call `getMapCell(3, 2)` several times, it needs to return the same thing each time. This code won't achieve that. It also has lots of other issues (e.g. if x=0 then it always returns 0, making lots of horizontal lines, and so on)

Comment: I had presumed that this was wrapped in a class that basically reset Random each time to the same seed and you were iterating through a range of x and y once. If you want to call getMapCell() several times with the same (x, y), I would suggest you accept Euphoric's answer.